Closeup needs insane LOD but not sure how to effectively achieve it
I have a shot that features camera very close to asphalt and I want to make it very realistic
but with the steep angle normal map doesn't cut it so I attempted to do it with displacement map: 
As seen here that's not nearly enough detail. But this is already nearly 7 million vertices, I don't think it's very practical to do like 20-40 mil vertices just on asphalt to make it presentable for a closeup. Does anyone know any optimization tips so I only add geometry detail where camera can see it and less detail further away where it's barely visible?

tbh i wouldn't use displacement, but "just" bump. And the second question is: if you are using depth of field (and i personally think you should) is there still a problem at all or is that blurry anyway?

I think this is bordering on opinion based question, but this looks like asphalt that's been put there a few days ago, whereas the rest of the scene looks like this parking lot is quite old, with the grunge on the columns and the tag in the back. Similarly to a realistic phone case rendering you need to add impefections, cracks, holes and the color needs to be more noisy. There should be some moss on the asphalt around the pillars for example. Also, the only place where there should be water (low roughness) is where the cars park, not in the driveway, it's an underground parking lot.

This is the job that adaptive subdivision was designed for: make vertex density relative to screen space rather than world space.  Searching for adaptive subdivision should get you what you need to know about it.

I would add detail via the roughness or base color before doing anything with displacement. Especially on a flat asphalt plane. I think you're confusing lack of detail from the normals with lack of detail in the roughness. Go look at some photos of asphalt and you will see; it looks almost like snow, mostly rough but with random sparkles all over. Then you add grease, tire marks, rain etc and there's tons of variation there.

Getting great tips so far will check out adaptive subdivision, cracks and holes, rain drops on the cars because they dragged in the water, maybe wet tire tracks. The biggest problem is the shiny smooth asphalt, and even with roughness map it wouldnt look great because this close you can already see the individual rocks which need detail hence I will see what the adaptive subdivision does.

As @Nathan pointed out adaptive subdivision turned out to be the saving grace. 
This allowed me to achieve amazing level of detail with little to no geometry. Just subdivided the floor into very large chunks and adaptive subdivision created geometry way more efficiently than constant subdivision.
Just need to set it to simple and the dicing scale to something like 0.8.
Was able to shave off 40 million faces with it for the same level of detail.
